# Superbox JS & Quicksand Combo Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicksand

I have a portfolio section here... http://bvh.delineamultimedia.com/?page_id=2 and Superbox - (http://toddmotto.com/introducing-superbox-the-reimagined-lightbox-gallery/) is working but after I click on a quicksand "filter" link the superbox seems to be disabled. Is there a way to fix this. Here is the JavaScript. I'm a bit confused as to why this is happening. I'm guessing quicksand is a bit greedy but am not for sure.

Thanks in advanced!

```
;(function($) {

$.fn.SuperBox = function(options) {

    var superbox      = $('<div class="superbox-show"></div>');
    var superboximg   = $('<img src="" class="superbox-current-img">');
    var superboxclose = $('<div class="superbox-close"></div>');

    superbox.append(superboximg).append(superboxclose);

    return this.each(function() {

        //$('.superbox-list').click(function() {
        $('.superbox').on('click', '.superbox-list', function() {

            var currentimg = $(this).find('.superbox-img');
            var imgData = currentimg.data('img');
            superboximg.attr('src', imgData);

            if($('.superbox-current-img').css('opacity') == 0) {
                $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 1});
            }

            if ($(this).next().hasClass('superbox-show')) {
                superbox.toggle();
            } else {
                superbox.insertAfter(this).css('display', 'block');
            }

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop:superbox.position().top - currentimg.width()
            }, 'medium');

        });

        $('.superbox').on('click', '.superbox-close', function() {
            $('.superbox-current-img').animate({opacity: 0}, 200, function() {
                $('.superbox-show').slideUp();
            });
        });

    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the quicksand filter is active, it sets a new height for the `filterable-grid` `ul` and also sets `overflow:hidden` which hides the superbox from being displayed.. is is being called properly, it is just hidden in the overflow of the `ul`.. may need to modify the `quicksand` script or find another work around..

Comment: I was thinking of something like this
  $('.superbox').on('click', '.superbox-list', function() {
Instead of
  $('.superbox-list').click(function() {

Comment: it is something to do with the QuickSand plugin. every time that the `ul` is filtered, the plugin sets a specific height for the `ul` and also adds `overflow: hidden` to the `ul`.. if you do not have the minified version of the QS plugin, you can run a search for `overflow` and change it accordingly.. i have removed the `overflow` through the code inspector in chrome and it worked fine..

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying. Let me see if I can find that.

Comment: or, you could add this to your superbox click function: `$('ul.filterable-grid').css({overflow: 'visible'});`

Comment: any time! enjoy that QS plugin, i've used it a bunch.

Comment: Will do. I hope this works out. I still have a lot more work to do.